# Remove a row in csv based on date Batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible with a batch script to remove a row based on a date it finds. The data would always have to be the current date.

SO I have a file that looks like this:

```
Group Id  Date         att_code
acme   1  04/02/2013     A
acme   2  05/06/2013     A
```

I want the batch file to remove the row that has `05/06/2013`. It will determine which ones to remove based on today's date. The data will not be in order.

Comment: Show more from the structure of your csv! Examples etc.

Comment: Group Id Date te 1 4/3/2013 te 2 4/3/2013 te 3 5/25/2013 te 4 5/26/2013 te 5 5/27/2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<source.csv>target.csv findstr /V "%date%"
```

Comment: I'm not understand source.csv, do I have to supply the Data on another CSV?

Comment: How many rows do you have and are there missing data or <space>'s in the cells?

Answer (score 0):

This *command line* should work:

```
findstr /V "%date%" theFile.csv
```

You may insert previous line in a Batch file, if you wish.

Comment: Group Id Date
te 1 4/3/2013
te 2 4/3/2013
te 3 5/25/2013
te 4 5/26/2013
te 5 5/27/2013

Comment: So how can I get it to print the the results into new csv?

Comment: `findstr /V "%date%" theFile.csv > new.csv`